# Display and aggregate time series based on map selection

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, time-series

My data is geospatial and consists in records of concentrations that are measured every day on fixed locations. I would like to display the time series of these records when I select one point of the map. If possible, I would like also to do an aggregation of the measures if I select many points.

I have been scrolling through QGIS documentation and look at plugins (TimeManager is great but does not do the job), widget, actions, tip preview, but I have not found a solution yet.

I precise that I run QGIS 3.2 and that my data is stored in PostGIS and every record has: `lon, lat, date, measure, name` where `lon, lat` are fixed for a given location name.

This can be done with Tableau, but I struggled to reproduce something similar with QGIS.

Example with Tableau: locations are selected on the right and time series of the selected locations are aggregated and display below

[image: Tableau example]

Comment: there is the [Data Analysis and Visualization](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/dataexplorer/) plugin that is directed at time series statistics. might not cover all you need, though. try it, I´ve had good and bad times using it. there was a simpler LiveStats plugin, but I´m not sure if it was ported to QGIS 3.x.

Comment: I have tried the data explorer plugin already but it does not work really well. The axes are not displayed and it throws python errors stating that max ticker is reached (>2000), despite only few features are selected on map